# Contour Integral of sin θ, cos θ

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

How to solve this question using contour integration

$$\int_0^{2π} \frac {sin^2 θ }{a + b cosθ} dθ $$

The problem what I am facing here is due to square of sinθ , it is getting very complicated and answer is not coming. Please help me out.

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ reals?

Comment: Yes. They are real

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $z=e^{i\theta}$ then
\begin{align}
I
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\sin^2\theta}{a+b\cos\theta}\, d\theta\\
&=\frac12\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1-\cos2\theta}{a+b\cos\theta}\, d\theta\\
&=\frac12\int_{|z|=1} \frac{{\bf Re\,}(1-z^2)}{a+b(z+z^{-1})}\,\dfrac{1}{iz} dz,\\
&={\bf Re\,}\dfrac{1}{2i}\int_{|z|=1} \frac{1-z^2}{bz^2+az+b}\, dz
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really helped me.

Comment: Answer here is $$ 2π ( a - \sqrt(a^2 -b^2) ) / (b^2) $$

Comment: Your welcome! It's depend on the roots of denominator lie in disk or not!

Comment: Yes, for |z| = 1 , I took one root lying within the disc and the answer came out to be correct.